# Multiple users working remotely on Tally ERP9

Tags: tally

I am not very sure whether this is the right forum to ask this question or not.

We are having a TallyERP9 server with Multiple Licenses. Now our 3 users working remotely on the same Data. We have set up Google Drive for Data Syncing. But most of the time its giving issue due to synchronisation process.
What could be the best soltion so that multiple users can work on same data from Remote Locations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using Google Drive for Data Syncing?

Comment: @MitaleeRao.. We are keeping data on Google drive and syncing that through Google Drive client.

Comment: There seem to be some rules here for data synchronization in Tally - http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TallyTips/GettingStartedwithDataSynchronisation.pdf .

Comment: @MitaleeRao.. Many thanks. I had a discussion with tally support team. They also recommended the same you gave. But it need additional license. Hence I am accepting your comment as Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer - http://mirror.tallysolutions.com/Downloads/TallyTips/GettingStartedwithDataSynchronisation.pdf

Thanks to @MitaleeRao...

Edit placed here for brevity:

These are 2 points I've noted regarding the Tally architecture:

1. The database is a flat file in a tree structure, and there are numerous checkpoints at each level for maintaining this inheritance (for e.g., a voucher has inventory entries that have stock items, which have units, etc.).
2. The SOAP XML protocol that Tally uses does not have multi-threading capabilities - i.e., the Tally server will only accept one request and give a response at a time.

The Data syncronisation that Tally has introduced is probably the automating of *exporting the XML of all masters/vouchers and importing them onto the central Database (whether on the Tally.NET server or on a local computer with a static IP)*. Not sure how the Google Drive client works, but I'm assuming it is a variation of the same (i.e., XML based data export and then import onto a main computer).